# JSON parse to change String attribute to an object atribute in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON object that one of the a attributes is a JSON string.

```
a = {
"dt" : "2022-01-02 00:00:00"
"fx": "{\"id\":1,\"faixaId\":1,\"speedAtivo\":true}",
"hash": "8c91a61a0a49b73de2fc13caed00e6a93dbe435b354216802da0dbe8bfda3300",
}
```

In JavaScript, I can convert the "fx" attribute to an object using:

```
a.fx = JSON.parse(a.fx)
```

And the new JSON:

```
a = {
"dt" : "2022-01-02 00:00:00"
"fx": {"id":1,
        "faixaId":1,
        "speedAtivo":true
      },
"hash": "8c91a61a0a49b73de2fc13caed00e6a93dbe435b354216802da0dbe8bfda3300",
}
```

There is a way to do this with Java?

Comment: Yes there are many ways to do a similar thing in Java. What have you tried so far? Did you run into any issues? Which library are you using?

Comment: Plus 1: it's straightforward and depends on the library you use

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can parse JSON string using one of these libraries
[to use these library check the docs](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/OpenSourceSoftware/Components/net.sf.json.htm) and
[maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.json/com.springsource.net.sf.json/1.0.0)

But make sure that your JSON is in correct format as the above JSON is missing comma after the first line ending.

Below is the simple example to parse a JSON String using the above library.

```
String jsonStr = "{\"dt\":\"2022-01-02 00:00:00\",
    \"fx\":\"id\":1,\"faixaId\":1,\"speedAtivo\":true},
   \"hash\":\"8c91accsiamkFVXtw6N7DnE3QtredADYBYU35b354216802da0dbe8bfda3300\", 
}";

JSONObject strObj = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonStr);
```

Output:

```
{
   "dt": "2022-01-02 00:00:00",
   "fx": {
       "id": 1,
       "faixaId": 1,
       "speedAtivo": true
   },
   "hash": 
   "8c91accsiamkFVXtw6N7DnE3QtredADYBYU35b354216802da0dbe8bfda3300"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson lirary to convert objects from JSON String to objects via custom deserializer.

First you create Classes that will represent the main object and fx object

```
public class AClass {
    public String dt;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)
    public FxClass fx;
    public String hash;
}

public class FxClass {
    public int id;
    public int faixaId;
    public boolean speedAtivo;
}
```

Then you create deserizalizer

```
public class Deserializer extends StdDeserializer<FxClass> {
    protected Deserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }
    protected Deserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Override
    public FxClass deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        TextNode treeNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(treeNode.asText(), FxClass.class);
    }
}
```

And add deserializer to ObjectMapperConfiguration

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(FxClass.class, new Deserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
```

And thats it. To convert JsonString to object

```
AClass readValue = new ObjectMapper.readValue(json, AClass.class);
```

For additional info try reading https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization